# Custom error message for input type date does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, unobtrusive-validation

I would like to create a custom error message for an input of type date. The rules are, the input is required. If an input is provided, it should be in the range from 1-1-1920 to lastyear (today's date minus one year). I've done the following
This is my input field:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-5 desktop-margin">
                                    <label for="DateofBirth" class="required-field">Date of birth</label>
                                    <input id="dob" name="dob" type="date" class="form-control" value="@Model.DateofBirth" data-val="true" data-rule-required="true" data-val-required="Date of birth is required." data-rule-customdate="true" data-val-customdate="Invalid date.">
                                    <div id="dobError" class="help-block field-validation-valid"></div>
                                </div>
```

and here is my jQuery:

```
$.validator.addMethod("customdate", function (value, element) {
        // Convert the input value to a Date object
        var selectedDate = new Date(value);

        // Get today's date and calculate the date one year ago
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var oneYearAgo = new Date();
        oneYearAgo.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() - 1);

        // Define the minimum and maximum allowed dates (1/1/1920 and today's date - 1 year)
        var minDate = new Date("1920-01-01");
        var maxDate = oneYearAgo;
        console.log("selectedDate is: " + selectedDate + " minimum date is: " + minDate + " maximum date is: " + maxDate); 
        // Check the conditions and return the result
        if (isNaN(selectedDate)) {
            console.log("no date was provided"); 
            createErrorSpan("Date of birth is required.");
            return false; // Date is not valid
        } else if (selectedDate > maxDate) {
            console.log("date is big"); 
            createErrorSpan("Date should occur before " + formatDate(maxDate) + ".");
            return false; // Date is bigger than today's date - 1 year
        } else if (selectedDate < minDate) {
            console.log("date is small"); 
            createErrorSpan("Date should occur after " + formatDate(minDate) + ".");
            return false; // Date is less than 1/1/1920
        }

        return true; // Date is valid and meets all conditions
    });

    // Adapter for customdate validation method
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("customdate", function (options) {
        options.rules["customdate"] = true;
        options.messages["customdate"] = options.message;
    });
    $("#dob").on("input", function () {
        var isValid = $("#MyForm").valid();
        console.log("input is triggered and its: " + isValid); 
        if (isValid) {
            if ($("#dobError").has("span").length > 0) {
                $("#dobError").find("span").remove();
            }
        }
    });
```

I have noticed after adding the logs that the function "customdate is not triggered except when I'm entering a valid date. For example, when the date is 2/2/2000, it's only triggered after entering the last zero in 2000. It will never be triggered when entering 2/2/2033. What am I missing?
Also, is there a better way of using $("MyForm").valid()? as this will trigger validation for all the fields in the form.

Comment: FYI - read the documentation.  The `.valid()` method can also be attached to a single field, not just the whole form.   I do not believe you can call a function from within `addMethod()`.  Anything dynamic like that would have to be wrapped inside a `function() { ... }`.  `createErrorSpan` is likely being ignored.  Again, thoroughly review the documentation and examples, as well as searching the thousands of other questions on SO.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky. I have been looking for the documentation or any relevant question but no use :(

Comment: Not sure how you can't find it.  Documentation is the first Google result:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/